# How to avoid "can't access tty; job control turned off" when boot to initramfs

Tags: console, busybox, initramfs

i'm testing my custom initramfs now, but everytime the log there will have the

"can't access tty; job control turned off".

The /dev in initramfs has four files: null, sda1, ttyS0. 
The kernel parameter is 'console=ttyS0'.

Also, i test ctrl+c, it works fine.So how could this problem heppen?
In busybox documentation,

> Why do I keep getting "sh: can't access tty; job control turned off"
>   errors? Why doesn't Control-C work within my shell? This isn't really
>   a uClibc question, but I'll answer it here anyways. Job control will
>   be turned off since your shell can not obtain a controlling terminal.
>   This typically happens when you run your shell on /dev/console. The
>   kernel will not provide a controlling terminal on the /dev/console
>   device. Your should run your shell on a normal tty such as tty1 or
>   ttyS0 and everything will work perfectly. If you REALLY want your
>   shell to run on /dev/console, then you can hack your kernel (if you
>   are into that sortof thing) by changing drivers/char/tty_io.c to
>   change the lines where it sets "noctty = 1;" to instead set it to "0".
>   I recommend you instead run your shell on a real console...

I type tty and it gives me /dev/console instead of /dev/ttyS0.

So, that's all information about this problem, hope some one can help me out:-)

Comment: are you running busybox inside your initramfs? then look for "cttyhack". Maybe do what it's doing if your building your own stuff. You can also run `script /dev/null`, or create a pty by other means.

Comment: [here you go](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brgl/busybox/master/shell/cttyhack.c). The //config: comments tell you everything you need to know, including a workaround. You can copy-paste it into an answer, something I cannot do on a phone.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by pizdelect, here is the solution: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brgl/busybox/master/shell/cttyhack.c.

For me, I simply use `::respawn:/bin/cttyhack /bin/sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Recompiling `cttyhack.c` is too troublesome, just wrap /bin/sh in a shell:

`setsid sh -c 'exec sh </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1'`

will work.

Comment: where do you type this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter solution:

```bash
exec setsid sh </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

If you just want to run `agetty`, then this is even shorter:

```bash
exec setsid agetty tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

Comment: What is "even shorter" than what?  And what does the user do with these commands?